# How can I pass or get the UserId and QuizId in URL in Vue Component? Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm able to get UserId(users table) & QuizId(quizzes table) in Vue Component but not able to pass the values in URL address.

quiz.blade:

```
    <quiz-component
   :times ="{{$quiz->minutes}}"
   :quizId="{{$quiz->id}}"
   :quiz-questions = "{{$quizQuestions}}"
   :has-quiz-played ="{{$authUserHasPlayedQuiz}}"
   :userId = "{{Auth::user()->id}}"
   >
   </quiz-component>
```

Code part from Component.vue:

```
<p>{{quizid}}</p> //here I'm able to get Quizid
<p>{{userid}}</p> //here I'm able to get UserId
-------------------------------
export default {
props:['quizid', 'quizQuestions', 'hasPlayedQuiz', 'times', 'userid'],
```

---

```
               axios.post('/quiz/create',{

                answerId:this.currentAnswer,
                questionId:this.currentQuestion,
                quizId :this.quizid,
                userId :this.userid,

            }).then((response)=>{
                console.log(response)
            }).catch((error)=>{
                alert("Error!")
            });
```

Now I want to pass the same userid and quizId in URL but url address opens-> http://quizmaster.test/statsquizresult/userId/quizId <-this.

Instead of this I want to get something like this URL->http://quizmaster.test/statsquizresult/2/8 <- for UserId is 2 and QuizId is 8.

```
data(){     

return{

            url_challenge: 'http://quizmaster.test/homeresult',

            url_self: 'http://quizmaster.test/statsquizresult/userId/quizId'

            // url_self: 'http://quizmaster.test/allquizresult'

        }
    },
```

I'm also having button which will take the user to his/her result:

```
<a v-bind:href="url_self"><button class="btn btn-info">View Result</button></a>
```

but the URL address not getting/passing the UserId and QuizId values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the `url_self` is static and not being passed the required ids.

To pass the required ids and get a dynamic url, you would have to use a computed property to describe what the url should be as it depends on the `quizid` and `userid` prop values:

```
export default {
    props: ['quizid', 'quizQuestions', 'hasPlayedQuiz', 'times', 'userid'],
    data() {
        return {
            ...
        }
    },
    computed: {
        url() {
            return `http://quizmaster.test/statsquizresult/${this.userid}/${this.quizid}`;         
        }
    }

}
```

You can then bind the `url()` to the href like so:

```
<a v-bind:href="url"><button class="btn btn-info">View Result</button></a>
```